Как решить эту проблему с Artifactory?
После обновления Artifactory на последнюю версию 7.90.13, в логи каждую минуту сыпятся ERROR вот такие:
2024-10-16T12:23:55.309Z 35[jfob ] [INFO ] [4c1fb02b398f1f37] [shipping_service.go:659       ] [main                ] - Uploading 9 consumption file/s to artifactory/api/v1/system/logs/usageartifactory/2024-10-16 with params map[nodeId:f6faff1b3f75 productName:artifactory serviceId:01bp25c3zv12q50j0vtw29072c], filelist: [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2024-10-16T09-53-37.106.log.gz /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2024-10-16T10-08-37.104.log.gz /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2024-10-16T10-23-37.104.log.gz /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2024-10-16T10-38-37.103.log.gz /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2024-10-16T10-53-37.104.log.gz /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2024-10-16T11-08-37.103.log.gz /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2024-10-16T11-23-37.103.log.gz /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2024-10-16T11-38-37.103.log.gz /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2024-10-16T11-53-37.103.log.gz] [shipping_service]
2024-10-16T12:23:55.330Z 35[jfob ] [ERROR] [4c1fb02b398f1f37] [artifactory_client.go:141     ] [main                ] - Upload file to Artifactory API returned: 404 {
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Not Found"
  } ]
} [artifactory_client]

Как я понял Artifactory пытается загрузить файлы журнала использования на URL API и получает 404.
Я проверял с помощью curl доступность, и у меня тоже код 404
curl -u username:password -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8082/artifactory/api/v1/system/logs/usageartifactory/"
При этом сам по себе API точно работает:
curl -u user:password "http://127.0.0.1:8082/artifactory/api/system/version"

Вывод:
{
  "version" : "7.90.13",
  "revision" : "79013900",
  "servicesVersions" : {
    "package_handler_version" : ""
  },
  "addons" : [ ],
  "license" : "Artifactory OSS",
  "entitlements" : {
    "EVENT_BASED_PULL_REPLICATION" : false,
    "SMART_REMOTE_TARGET_FOR_EDGE" : false,
    "REPO_REPLICATION" : false,
    "MULTIPUSH_REPLICATION" : false
  }
}


При выполнении этой команды
curl -u user:password -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8082/artifactory/api/system/usage"
Получаем такой вывод:
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "Cannot invoke \"org.artifactory.metrics.model.IntegrationsProductUsage.getProductId()\" because \"productUsageData\" is null"
  } ]

Естественно сам Artifactory запускается и все его сервисы тоже. Если нужна какая-то дополнительная информация - готов предоставить.

Я почему-то плохо прогуглил этот вопрос. Я попробовал ещё раз по-другому. Итак, мне помогло отредактировать файл system.yaml и добавить в него следующие строчки:
observability:
  consumption:
    allow: ""

